# Laravel cache error: Too few arguments to function {closure}(), 0 passed in .../Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php on line 426 and exactly 2 expected

Tags: php, laravel, caching

So I have a table called styles which has classes and styles for various places in blade templates. The table has a unique column the name and a column for class and a column for style. These values i do not expect to change much so I wish to cache them. The functions I have added to a helper class are listed below.

What I'm trying to do is cache a string so it can be called back later without the database query. So in my blade file I have a line like this `<table class="{{ getStyles('table', 'class') ">` and my helper file has the following functions

```
function getStyles( $name, $type )
{
    if ( $type === 'class' ) {
        $key = $name . 'Classes';
    } else {
        $key = $name . 'Styles';
    }
    if ( Cache::has( $key ) ) {
        return Cache::get( $key );
    }

    return cacheStyles( $name, $type );
}

function cacheStyles( $name, $type )
{
    if ( $type === 'class' ) {
        $key = $name . 'Classes';
    } else {
        $key = $name . 'Styles';
    }
    return Cache::rememberForever(
        $key,
        function ( $name, $type ) {
            return DB::table( 'styles' )->where( 'name', $name )->first()->{$type};
        }
    );
}

function updateStyles( $name, $class, $style )
{
    DB::table( 'styles' )
        ->where( 'name', $name )
        ->update(
            array(
                'class' => $class,
                'style' => $style
            )
        );
    cacheStyles( $name, 'class' );
    cacheStyles( $name, 'style' );

    return true;
}
```

I have cleared routes cache etc and I load the page with this table and i get the above error.

The closure function does have 2 arguments and they are strings ($name which is 'table' and $type which is 'class') so why the error?

I am caching to phpredis if it makes a difference. I also think I had this working (but it may have been cached with an earlier version of the code). Prior to clearing the cache I had added the 4 events into EventServiceProvider.php

```
        CacheHit::class => [
            LogCacheHit::class,
        ],

        CacheMissed::class => [
            LogCacheMissed::class,
        ],

        KeyForgotten::class => [
            LogKeyForgotten::class,
        ],

        KeyWritten::class => [
            LogKeyWritten::class,
        ],
```

I also added the listeners for these with no further amends (methods are empty). Do not know if related but once I cleared the cache My code stopped.

The prior method used was getTableClass but I switched to make it generic. Consequently the closure function originally had no $name and $class.

So I guess my question is 2 fold, am i using closure wrong and how can i stop this error?

I am using Laravel9.10 and php8.1 on an Ubuntu22.04 box

thanks

*** EDIT ***
So I read I can use 'use' and moved the 2 variables into this but i now get a new error `Attempt to read property "class" on null` which implies the paramenters are still not being passed into this closure.

```
function cacheStyles( $name, $type )
{
    if ( $type === 'class' ) {
        $key = $name . 'Classes';
    } else {
        $key = $name . 'Styles';
    }
    return Cache::rememberForever(
        $key,
        function () use ( $name, $type )
        {
            return DB::table( 'styles' )->where( 'name', $name )->first()->{$type};
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Which is line 426?

Comment: Apparently it's not finding a style with that name, so the attempt to get the class property fails

Comment: I think it's less error prone (and looks nicer) if you did `DB::table( 'styles' )->where( 'name', $name )->value($type)` which means get the column `$type` of the first row of the result. However it's not good form to update your question as soon as your original problem is solved. You can't expect us to keep trying to hit a moving target. If your original problem is solved then go ahead and diagnose your new problem and if you can't figure that out you can ask a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rememberForever()` second parameter accepts a closure without any parameters.
You can't link it to values other that the key itself (indirectly)

```
function cacheStyles( $name, $type )
{
    if ( $type === 'class' ) {
        $key = $name . 'Classes';
    } else {
        $key = $name . 'Styles';
    }

    return Cache::rememberForever(
        $key,
        function () use($name, $type) {
            return DB::table( 'styles' )->where( 'name', $name )->value($type);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Using use worked. My real issue beyond that was I was looking for a row with a name of table but it was in the database as tables. I renamed the rows name value and it now works.

Comment: @CraigStanfield you should also use `->value($type)` instead of `first()` then the attribute. Edited in the answer